# Extract some values in formatted string

Tags: c#, regex, string, field, extract

I would like to retrieve values in string formatted like this :

```
public var any:int = 0;
public var anyId:Number = 2;
public var theEnd:Vector.<uint>;
public var test:Boolean = false;
public var others1:Vector.<int>;
public var firstValue:CustomType;
public var field2:Boolean = false;
public var secondValue:String = "";
public var isWorks:Boolean = false;
```

I want to store field name, type and value in a custom class Property :

```
public class Property
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And with a Regex expression get these values.

How can I do ?

Thanks

**EDIT :** I tried this but I don't know how to go further with vectors..etc

```
    /public var ([a-zA-Z0-9]*):([a-zA-Z0-9]*)( = \"?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\"?)?;/g
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Ok, have a look at [this demo](http://ideone.com/i4ss9U). Let me know if I should post it, or if you prefer a LINQ-based example.

Comment: @stribizhev this should be an answer. BTW you can parse multiline strings in .NET regular expressions, you don't need to include newlines in the pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, posting my regex-based answer.

Your regex - `/public var ([a-zA-Z0-9]*):([a-zA-Z0-9]*)( = \"?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\"?)?;/g` - contains regex delimiters, and they are not supported in C#, and thus are treated as literal symbols. You need to remove them and the modifier `g` since to obtain multiple matches in C# `Regex.Matches`, or `Regex.Match` with `while` and `Match.Success`/`.NextMatch()` can be used.

The regex I am using is [`(?<=\s*var\s*)(?<name>[^=:\n]+):(?<type>[^;=\n]+)(?:=(?<value>[^;\n]+))?`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%5Cs*var%5Cs*)(%3F%3Cname%3E%5B%5E%3D%3A%5Cn%5D%2B)%3A(%3F%3Ctype%3E%5B%5E%3B%3D%5Cn%5D%2B)(%3F%3A%3D(%3F%3Cvalue%3E%5B%5E%3B%5Cn%5D%2B))%3F&i=public%20var%20any%3Aint%20%3D%200%3B%0D%0Apublic%20var%20anyId%3ANumber%20%3D%202%3B%0D%0Apublic%20var%20theEnd%3AVector.%3Cuint%3E%3B%0D%0Apublic%20var%20test%3ABoolean%20%3D%20false%3B%0D%0Apublic%20var%20others1%3AVector.%3Cint%3E%3B%0D%0Apublic%20var%20firstValue%3ACustomType%3B%0D%0Apublic%20var%20field2%3ABoolean%20%3D%20false%3B%0D%0Apublic%20var%20secondValue%3AString%20%3D%20%22%22%3B%0D%0Apublic%20var%20isWorks%3ABoolean%20%3D%20false%3B). The newline symbols are included as negated character classes can match a newline character.

```
var str = "public var any:int = 0;\r\npublic var anyId:Number = 2;\r\npublic var theEnd:Vector.<uint>;\r\npublic var test:Boolean = false;\r\npublic var others1:Vector.<int>;\r\npublic var firstValue:CustomType;\r\npublic var field2:Boolean = false;\r\npublic var secondValue:String = \"\";\r\npublic var isWorks:Boolean = false;";
var rx = new Regex(@"(?<=\s*var\s*)(?<name>[^=:\n]+):(?<type>[^;=\n]+)(?:=(?<value>[^;\n]+))?");
var coll = rx.Matches(str);
var props = new List<Property>();
foreach (Match m in coll)
    props.Add(new Property(m.Groups["name"].Value,m.Groups["type"].Value, m.Groups["value"].Value));
foreach (var item in props)
    Console.WriteLine("Name = " + item.Name + ", Type = " + item.Type + ", Value = " + item.Value);
```

Or with LINQ:

```
var props = rx.Matches(str)
          .OfType<Match>()
          .Select(m => 
               new Property(m.Groups["name"].Value, 
                   m.Groups["type"].Value, 
                   m.Groups["value"].Value))
          .ToList();
```

And the class example:

```
public class Property
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public Property()
    {}
    public Property(string n, string t, string v)
    {
        this.Name = n;  
        this.Type = t;
        this.Value = v;
    }
}
```

**NOTE ON PERFORMANCE**:

The regex is not the quickest, but it certainly beats the one in the other answer. Here is a test performed at [regexhero.net](http://regexhero.net/tester):

[image]

Comment: I guess this is it, but if you have more questions, please feel free to drop a comment.

Comment: You can use non-greedy matches instead of negation, eg. `(?<name>\w+?)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: With `name`, why not, but I tried to keep the regex as generic as possible. When dealing with regex-based delimiter matching I prefer negated classes.

Comment: Thank you, it works fine !
I edit the pattern a little to avoid space : "(?<=\s*var \s*)(?<name>[^=:\n]+):(?<type>[^;=\n]+) (?:= (?<value>[^;\n]+))?"

Comment: @stribizhev it's more generic when you *don't* have to add every non-matching class. You can use `\S` in the other elements to match non-whitespace characters

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Add your own answer then if you know better. I test all I post, and I know that works. `\S` is bad as it allows all delimiters.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: See my test results obtained at regexhero.net. I win :)

Comment: @stribizhev didn't know there's a contest. Besides, are you sure the reason for the difference is the non-greedy match or `\S` instead of eg capturing `visibility` and `var` as well?

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that you don't want *regular expressions*; in a simple case
as you've provided:

```
  String text =
    @"public var any:int = 0;
      public var anyId:Number = 2;
      public var theEnd:Vector.<uint>;
      public var test:Boolean = false;
      public var others1:Vector.<int>;
      public var firstValue:CustomType;
      public var field2:Boolean = false;";

  List<Property> result = text
    .Split(new Char[] {'\r','\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(line => {
       int varIndex = line.IndexOf("var") + "var".Length;
       int columnIndex = line.IndexOf(":") + ":".Length;
       int equalsIndex = line.IndexOf("="); // + "=".Length;
       // '=' can be absent
       equalsIndex = equalsIndex < 0 ? line.Length : equalsIndex + "=".Length;

       return new Property() {
         Name = line.Substring(varIndex, columnIndex - varIndex - 1).Trim(),
         Type = line.Substring(columnIndex, columnIndex - varIndex - 1).Trim(),
         Value = line.Substring(equalsIndex).Trim(' ', ';')
       };
    })
    .ToList();
```

if text can contain *comments* and other staff, e.g.

```
  "public (*var is commented out*) var sample: int = 123;;;; // another comment"
```

you have to implement a *parser*

Comment: Even in this "simple" case regular expressions are simpler and more maintainable than string splitting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following pattern:

```
\s*(?<vis>\w+?)\s+var\s+(?<name>\w+?)\s*:\s*(?<type>\S+?)(\s*=\s*(?<value>\S+?))?\s*;
```

to match each element in a line. Appending `?` after a quantifier results in a non-greedy match which makes the pattern a lot simpler - no need to negate all unwanted classes.

Values are optional, so the value group is wrapped in another, optional group `(\s*=\s*(?<value>\S+?))?`

Using the `RegexOptions.Multiline` option means we don't have to worry about accidentally matching newlines.

The C# 6 syntax in the following example isn't required, but multiline string literals and interpolated strings make for much cleaner code.

```
var input= @"public var any:int = 0;
            public var anyId:Number = 2;
            public var theEnd:Vector.<uint>;
            public var test:Boolean = false;
            public var others1:Vector.<int>;
            public var firstValue:CustomType;
            public var field2:Boolean = false;
            public var secondValue:String = """";
            public var isWorks:Boolean = false;";

var pattern= @"\s*(?<vis>\w+?)\s+var\s+(?<name>\w+?)\s*:\s*(?<type>\S+?)(\s*=\s*(?<value>\S+?))?\s*;"
var regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
var results=regex.Matches(input);
foreach (Match m in results)
{
    var g = m.Groups;
    Console.WriteLine($"{g["name"],-15} {g["type"],-10} {g["value"],-10}");
}

var properties = (from m in results.OfType<Match>()
                    let g = m.Groups
                    select new Property
                    {
                        Name = g["name"].Value,
                        Type = g.["type"].Value,
                        Value = g["value"].Value
                    })
                    .ToList();
```

I would consider using a parser generator like ANTLR though, if I had to parse more complex input or if there are multiple patterns to match. Learning how to write the grammar takes some time, but once you learn it, it's easy to create parsers that can match input that would require very complicated regular expressions. Whitespace management also becomes a lot easier

In this case, the grammar could be something like:

```
property   : visibility var name COLON type (EQUALS value)? SEMICOLON;
visibility : ALPHA+;
var        : ALPHA ALPHA ALPHA;
name       : ALPHANUM+;
type       : (ALPHANUM|DOT|LEFT|RIGHT);
value      : ALPHANUM
           | literal;
literal    : DOUBLE_QUOTE ALPHANUM* DOUBLE_QUOTE;

ALPHANUM   : ALPHA
           | DIGIT;
ALPHA      : [A-Z][a-z];
DIGIT      : [0-9];
...
WS         : [\r\n\s] -> skip;
```

With a parser, adding eg comments would be as simple as adding `comment` before `SEMICOLON` in the `property` rule and a new `comment` rule that would match the pattern of a comment